# C# MailMessage AlternateViews displaying HTML tags

Tags: c#, html, mailmessage

I am using MailMessage in C# to send out a HTML email. The code I am using is as follows

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<B>Test Message</B>", null, "text/html");
msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

I use the Alternate view because I need to attach files and embed images in the email body. When I send out the email to my gmail account, I see the HTML tags displayed in the inbox. Clicking on the message to view the actual email gets rid of the tags. How do I ensure that the tags do not display in the inbox?

Thanks

I solved the issue. I am posting the solution as an answer to my own question to help others who may run into the same issue

My code had

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.Body = "<B>Test Message</B>";
AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<B>Test Message</B>", null, "text/html");
msg.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

The second line of code needed to be removed since I was specifying both a body and an alternate view which was causing problems.

Answer (score 3):

Does the message itself need to be marked around `isBodyHtml` ?

```
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Comment: I have msg.IsBodyHtml = true set but that doesnt help